# How to replace excel #DIV/0! error with 0, blank or certain text?

Tags: excel

in excel i have formula in C1 =A1:B2 and if the result is 0 it is written #DEL/0!

How to change this error that is going to be written 0?

Thank you

Comment: Try the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5). I don't know what language `#DEL/0!` is but you can change the EN-US to your own regional language to get the correct page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `If` statement to check if the divisor is zero, and display a warning instead of the calculation

[image: Divide by zero example]

Comment: this one is write :) =IF(ISBLANK(A1);"";IF(ISBLANK(B1);"";A1/B1))

thanku u